# SQL For every two items A and B, at what frequency is B bought after A

Tags: sql, sql-server, frequency

I have a table that lists items that were in each transaction and the sequence in which they were purchased.

sequence ID = 1 means it's the first item, sequence ID = 2 means it's the second item.

```
transaction_id  item.id   sequence_id    transection_time
---------------------------------------------------------
  1                1            1           12:00:00.000
  1                1            2           12:00:00.000
  1                2            3           12:00:00.000     
  2                1            1           12:10:00.000      
  2                2            2           12:10:00.000 
  2                3            3           12:10:00.000
```

I want to make a query which presents for every two items, for example, 1 and 2, at what frequency is 1 purchased after 2.

clarification:

- 2 is bought after 1 if they both appear in a transaction and 2 sequence ID is higher than 1
- cases when an item bought twice in the same transaction, does not count, for example, item 1 bought after item 1 in the same transaction does not count.

from my table, the answer should be

```
p.before        p.after   frequency(hour)
--------------------------------------
  1                2            2/60       
  1                3            1/60    
  2                3            1/60
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . this sounds like a self-join:

```
select t1.item_id, t2.item_id, count(distinct t1.transaction_id)
from transactions t1 join
     transactions t2
     on t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id and
        t1.sequence_id < t2.sequence_id and
        t1.item_id <> t2.item_id
group by t1.item_id, t2.item_id;
```

Note that a transaction could (at least theoretically) have 1 --> 2 --> 1.  Such a transaction would be counted both for (1, 2) and (2, 1).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e0e3c0c040e268a8c8713b6af9cb72a4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Spot on @Gordon